# Web Services Properties missing from Application Configuration in WebSphere

Tags: java, web-services, deployment, websphere

I have an application in which Web Services are there.

When I deployed one the **Web Services Properties** is appearing as shown in the image.
[image: Jpeg with properties]

After deploying the same application with different name and context root the **Web Services Properties** is not appearing.
[image: Jpeg without properties]

What did I miss while deploying the second application such that the **Web Services Properties** is not appearing ?

**N.B. The applications are deployed on different servers. So is there any configuration we should do while creating servers that will support web-service deployment**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit hard to solve just like that without any details on the applications you have and what path you took to get to the second deployed application.

I have found though that the main reason for a section or item about the application being missing is that WebSphere does not recognize the application to have that capability. In the cases I have found this is because of deployment descriptor inconsistencies, for example:

- the deployment descriptors being in the wrong JEE version format
- One binding file referring to an ID of a item in another file, but that item actually has another ID (development tools can sometimes "help" you cause these inconsistencies.

I suggest you try to do a compare of the deployment descriptor files between the two deployed versions of the application.

If the application is exactly the same and you just changed these parameters at deployment, look for naming conflicts.

Comment: The Deployment Descriptor files are the same, the same **WAR** file was used to deploy in both the cases. It might not be the DD configuration, I am thinking about missing some configuration while deploying in the servers.

Comment: Are you deploying the wars directly or are you deploying them in ears?

Comment: I am deploying the wars directly using WebSphere console.

Comment: Then it does not sound like anything being inconsistent. Any naming conflicts?

Comment: No Naming conflicts. There is only one web service being used in the application and that itself is not getting deployed.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the application installation-logs for hints.

We had a similar problem: the webservices did not appear in the AdminConsole in the UAT environment (ND (cluster)), while worked fine in TEST (standalone (single)).
Finally we found that the java (sdk) version of the DeploymentManager was not changed to java1.7, only the AppServers (the DMGR and the NodeAgents were left on default 1.6 ), so during the application deployment it could not resolve/generate the annotations..

There was an error message in DeploymentManager8/logs/dmgr/SystemOut.log during appl. installation :
"WSModuleDescr E   WSWS7027E: JAX-WS Service Descriptions could not be correctly built because of the following error: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: WSWS7054E: The Web Services Description Language (WSDL) file could not be generated for the [****] Web service implementation class because of the following error: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version"

We set the jvm sdk to java1.7 on the AdminConsole for the DeploymentManager, and the Nodeagents, and reinstalled the application, that solved the problem.
( 
AdminConsole > System administration > Deployment manager > Java SDKs > Make default: java 1.7 
...
More info on setting 1.7 java: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1209_hall/1209_hall.html 
)

You can check the java version on Linux in the process list ("ps -ef |grep java", or "[WAS8_installdir]/java_1.7.1_64/bin/java -version", or "[WAS8_installdir]/bin/versionInfo.sh" )

(
More info on JAX-WS: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/twbs_devwbsjaxws.html
)